# How can I reset my "Time spent on Page" Timer when my seconds go over 60 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, alert, box

So I got an alertbox that shows your current time spent on the page.. the problem is that if it goes over 60 seconds it does not reset to 0 seconds. I dont know how to fix that and I didnt find any solution by searching... my current code:

```
var d = new Date();
var elapsed = new Date() - d;
var seconds = parseInt(elapsed / 1000);
var minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60);
alert("Time spent on page: " + minutes + " Minute/s " + seconds + " Scond/s");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common logic problem.  Just take the remainder.

```
var d = new Date();
var elapsed = new Date() - d;
var totalseconds = parseInt(elapsed  / 1000);  
var minutes = parseInt(totalSeconds / 60);
var seconds = totalSeconds % 60; //Take only remainder (modulus)
```

Comment: thank you so much :D  I thought I had to reset the time or something, but I totally forgot about modulu . thx ;)